# Paired design and building a GLM

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, nested-data, paired-data

I am blocking a bit on the choice of a model for my data. 
The study is applying 2 different stimuli (S1 and S2) on some animals. Each stimuli has two 'treatments': either 'on' or 'off' (off being the control).

The study has been done in a matched way, that means at the same time, T1 on and T1 off are performed in the same location.  I could forget about the "matched" controls and treatments and just pooled all the data together but I was wondering if I could produce a new variable, called "trial" for example, that matches each experiments (on and off together) and then use this in the model.

To sum up:

- fixed effect: stimuli (S1_ON, S2_ON, Control)
- random effects:

--date(Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday),

--location(city1, city2),

--trials(trial1, trial2.... trial30)

Using a negative binomial (overdispersed count data) from the MASS package:

```
M1 <- nb.glm(counts ~ stimuli/trials + location + date, data=data)
```

Could anyone advice if that makes sense at all?

I would be happy to try to make it clearer if it is not! Thank you!